# Getting the name of a DLL from within the dll

Tags: c++, c, windows

If I have a dll called "foo.dll" and the end user renames it to "bar.dll". After calling to a LoadLibrary, how can I get the name "bar.dll" from inside my dll?

Is it GetModuleFileName(hModule, buffer); ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, you need to store hModule in [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(VS.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  DWORD fdwReason,  LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  switch (fdwReason)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      hModule = hinstDLL;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885202.aspx) function, store the module handle you get passed in a static variable, and then use that variable to call [GetModuleFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx). You should avoid calling GetModuleFilename (or any other function) in DllMain itself, as Windows is very picky about what you can and can't do in there.